# Center v-toolbar-title

Tags: css, vue.js, flexbox, vuetify.js

I would like to center my title in my toolbar component.
This is what it's looke like :

[image]

And this is my component :

```
<div>
    <v-navigation-drawer dark app clipped temporary v-model="menu" class="teal white--text">
        <v-list >
            <v-list-tile
               v-for="(item,index) in items" :key="index" @click="$router.push(item.path)" v-if="item.value">
                <v-list-tile-action>
                    <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
                </v-list-tile-action>
                <v-list-tile-content>
                    <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.label }}</v-list-tile-title>
                </v-list-tile-content>
            </v-list-tile>
        </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-toolbar dense dark color="teal" class="pa-0">
        <router-link to="/">
            <v-btn class="mx-0" icon>
                <i class="material-icons">home</i>
            </v-btn>
        </router-link>
        <v-toolbar-title class="white--text">{{title}}</v-toolbar-title>
        <v-layout align-center justify-end>
            <v-toolbar-items>
                <router-link to="/parametres">
                    <v-btn class="mx-0" icon>
                        <i class="material-icons">settings</i>
                    </v-btn>
                </router-link>
                <v-btn v-on:click="Logout()" class="mx-0" icon>
                    <i class="material-icons">exit_to_app</i>
                </v-btn>
            </v-toolbar-items>
        </v-layout>
    </v-toolbar>
</div>
```

I can not center it properly in relation to the toolbar. Maybe should i use flex properties ? By the way i'm using Vuetify.js for the material design.

If you can help me I'll be grateful.
I'm totally new with flex and vuejs.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Add a `v-spacer` before the title

```
<v-spacer></v-spacer>
<v-toolbar-title class="white--text">{{title}}</v-toolbar-title>
```

[image]

A more complex alternative would be to use the [grid](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids) layout with [flex](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/flex) spacing

```
<v-toolbar dense dark color="teal" class="pa-0">
  <v-row>
    <v-col cols="2">
      ...
    </v-col>
    <v-col class="d-flex justify-space-around">
      <v-toolbar-title class="white--text">{{title}}</v-toolbar-title>
    </v-col>
    <v-col cols="2" class="d-flex justify-end">
      ...
    </v-col>
</v-toolbar>
```

Answer (score 14):

In my case, I had only `<v-toolbar-title>`, so I had to put `<v-spacer />` both on the right and left of it:

```
<v-toolbar>
  <v-spacer />
  <v-toolbar-title>
    Some title text
  </v-toolbar-title>
  <v-spacer />
</v-toolbar>
```

Comment: Technically <v-spacer /> does not center... if offsets based on the length of content to the left and or right.

Answer (score 8):

I added **flex text-center** classes to the **v-toolbar-title** tag. These classes centered the title.

```
<v-toolbar-title class="flex text-center">
      <h4>Centered Title</h4>
 </v-toolbar-title>
```

Comment: This works great but where did you get   class="flex text-center"   from? all the docs I have seen use d-flex but    class="d-flex text-center"    does not work.